# Spark WindowedApplication, monitor keyUp event

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I have a WindowedApplication, I need to monitor a `keyUp` so that I can close the application on the escape key pressed. However, my code is not working:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       keyUp="windowedapplication1_keyUpHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[   

            protected function windowedapplication1_keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                //Monitor key press {ESC}
                if(event.keyCode == 27){
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    trace("key = " + event.keyCode);
                }
            }   

        ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

It seems that this event is not firing at all, I've even tried to override the `keyUpHandler` and trace out some info, but nothing.

Comment: Are you getting any keyboard events?

Comment: @ethrbunny: No, but I've actually just solved and am about to post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this similar question](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/700419) on the Adobe forums, it helped solve the problem.

I solved by listening for `applicationComplete` and then in the handler attaching the `keyUp` listener to the `stage`.

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       applicationComplete="init()">

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[   

            protected function init():void
            {
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, windowedapplication1_keyUpHandler);
            }

            protected function windowedapplication1_keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                //Monitor key press {ESC}
                if(event.keyCode == 27){
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    trace("key = " + event.keyCode);
                }
            }       

        ]]>
</fx:Script>
```